# Python BeautifulSoup - Create dataframe using html tags between <div>

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a html website without any tables and I want to scrap data in form of a table.
Here is the sample html code

```
    <div class='ah-content'
      <h4>XYZ Community</h4>
      <p>123 Street</p>
      <p>Atlanta, Georgia, 12345</p>
      <p>1234567890</p>
     </div>
```

It is a long list like this and I want to capture `<h4>` and `<p>` between `<div>`

So, the output will be:

| Name | Address | Address2 | Phone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xyz Community | 123 Street | Atlanta, Georgia, 12345 | 1234567890 |

Comment: all items are inside only one div or each item is inside a div?

Comment: Hi,  all 4 items (h4 and p) are inside only one div. After every </div> a new div section begins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all `<div class='ah-content'>` follows the same pattern like in your example you can use this script to create a DataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = """\
<div class='ah-content'>
  <h4>XYZ Community</h4>
  <p>123 Street</p>
  <p>Atlanta, Georgia, 12345</p>
  <p>1234567890</p>
 </div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

strings = [[t.text for t in c.find_all()] for c in soup.select(".ah-content")]

df = pd.DataFrame(strings, columns=["Name", "Address", "Address2", "Phone"])
print(df.to_markdown(index=False))
```

Prints:

| Name | Address | Address2 | Phone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XYZ Community | 123 Street | Atlanta, Georgia, 12345 | 1234567890 |